# Why does NOT my ImageView change its ScaleType programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, android-imageview

I have an `ImageView` called `"alumniImage"` which I set it programmatically to `ScaleType` of `CENTERCROP`.

But in the app it doesn't seem to change.

Here is the code for it:

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
(int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.survey_height), // 50dp
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    ImageView alumniImage = new ImageView(getContext()); //because I am in a fragment
    alumniImage.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
    alumniImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.alumni_survey);
    alumniImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    alumniLayout.addView(alumniImage);
```

I tried to use the debugger and nothing changed.

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Why is this happening?!

BTW I tried to put that `ImageView` in an xml file and it worked fine.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen shot clued me into what's going on.

Your debugger's current line is a *blank line of source code*.

Whenever I get that, it means I am debugging an APK that is outdated.  The source code has changed, but the APK hasn't been rebuilt.

Clean your project, rebuild everything and try again.  You should see what you expect.

Oh yeah, and if you're using Instant Run, turn it off.  That thing never notices when I update anything.

Answer (score 1):

Because ImageView drawed image before you set `scaleType`. So, it used default `scaleType` (FIT_CENTER),

set `scaleType` before `setImageResource`.

```
alumniImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
alumniImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.alumni_survey);
```

And i suggest to you set `LayoutParams` in `addView` method

```
alumniLayout.addView(alumniImage, imageParams);
```